# Expression throws error inside tryCatch but evaluates fine outside it

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, try-catch

I have a small block of code in a Shiny application which uses SQLite connection and dplyr to fetch the number of rows based on certain filter conditions. The problem is that when I run the operation inside tryCatch, it throws an error but when I run it outside tryCatch it runs fine. Here is a reprex:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(tibble)
library(DBI)

# Create a connection object with SQLite
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
  RSQLite::SQLite(),
  "master.sqlite3"
)

# Creating the source table
create_pool_query = "CREATE TABLE pool (
pool_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL,
pool_name                       TEXT NOT NULL,
year                            INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pool_pk PRIMARY KEY (pool_id, year)
)"

dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pool")
dbExecute(conn, create_pool_query)

# This is the part from Shiny App
# Fetching count of selected pool name from DB table. 
# Tried replacing the variables in below filter statement with string and integer values.
# Still same issue
tryCatch({
      exist_cnt <- nrow(conn %>%
                          tbl('pool') %>%
                          filter((pool_name == !!dat$pool_name) & (year == !!dat$year)) %>%
                          collect())
    },error = function(error){
      msg = "Error validating existing pool count."
      print(msg)
      print(error)
      error
    })
```

I put a browser just before this block and tried evaluating it in console. That works but evaluating inside the tryCatch gives me this error:

```
debug at #2: exist_cnt <- nrow(conn %>% tbl("pool") %>% filter((pool_name == 
    "abcd") & (year == 2021)) %>% collect())
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is `dat` ?

Comment: that is a list I created using user inputs. I replaced those variables with fixed values "abcd" and 2021 respectively and still got the same error

Comment: could you add a `dat` object to your example? It is not reproducible as it is.

Comment: Using `dat=list(pool_name="abcd", year=2021)`, I get no error, neither inside or outside `trycatch()`. What error do you get (the one you gave is just the debugger)? You should try to use `reprex::reprex()` when posting, as it gives you a result independent from your environment.

Comment: @DanChaltiel - Yes, you are right. I realized this error only occurs inside the tryCatch when ran in Debugger. Thanks for pointing that out!